# How to fix error caused by userconfig probably by sails?

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

Im following this tutorial to set up a simple nodejs in docker with the help of sails. So far so good, but I keep getting this one error that it cant start the app because it misses a hook('userconfig'). I cant post the image due to a reputation below 10, so here is the link to it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTgwa.jpg)

The versions i use are:
sails: 1.1.0
sails-mongo: 6.5.0

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the code or an import in your `config/bootstrap.js` file. Do you have this file or have you modified it from the default stuff that comes in there?

Comment: I jave not modified the code. The code in config/bootstrap.js is the same as in the example. For now im looking at the node_modules.

Comment: It may be helpful to know the Node.js version you're running as well